# Extjs 6 Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing Remove Update / Cancel buttons

Tags: extjs6

I am trying to remove update cancel buttons.
but no any config's are available for this.
I have tried to override but i cant remove this.

please if you have done task like this or know how to do this help me.

Answer (score 1):

You're absolutely right that there is no built-in way to hide the update and cancel buttons with the row editing plugin.

You *could* try to hide the button bar via CSS. The normal CSS class name is `x-grid-row-editor-buttons`. But this may cause other problems.

Or, you could try a different editor, such as the [`CellEditing`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing.html) plugin - this lets you edit one cell at a time, as opposed to showing the editors for the entire row, and doesn't use buttons.

Comment: oh thanks very much,
i knew css way , but I'm trying to do this job with js.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to remove the button by overriding the `Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing`. A quick look at the source shows me an array with in the `initEditiorFunction()` which looks like this.

```
btns = ['saveBtnText', 'cancelBtnText', 'errorsText', 'dirtyText'],
```

Try removing the `cancelBtnText` button, and perhaps it won't show on there? I haven't tested this but this might be something in the right direction.

Comment: I have tested this one , remove all array items but it still renders ..

Comment: Hmm, I tried digging through the source and can't seem to find where else those buttons would come from. I will try some other things outside the CSS hacks to hide the button, and I will get back to you